# Put SQL array data append to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE 1") or die(mysql_error());
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    echo ''.$info['value'].
    '<br>';
}
```

Here the value of sql is showing, my question is how can i add div or other attribute ?
 For example

```
echo '<img src = "'.$info['value'] .'" />'; // Convert into javascript append type

$("#messages").append("<img src='"+ value +"'/>");
```

I cannot use `<?php echo ?>` the required data is on other page and i'm using ajax to take into main page but i cannot understand how can append the array data

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to append using `Javascript`?
Why not echo the tags appropriately and include whatever attributes you want?

Comment: Cannot do because its showing some problem css hover which cannot be prevented

Answer (score 0):

You can only make that if you use `ajax` in jQuery.

> **PHP is executed in server** and **javascript in client navigator** so when jQuery see your page, it see only an html file because the
>   server send only html file.

You can create your jQuery with echo in PHP but it's a dirty solution.

Comment: Donovan can you elaborate the process please ? I think I'm using same process

Comment: If you read my post, your php and jQuery, even if are writen in the same page, are not executed in the same time. When you load page, the server execute your PHP and send an html file to the client. When the navigator receive this html file, it execute the javascript. Otherwise, you can also write all jQuery script in your php with `echo`, but it's a very dirty solution.